# SOQL Relationship query

Tags: soql

I'm trying to query using a very basic line of code. I have a lookup relationship from Account to a custom object (1:1 or 1:many). Below is the query;

SELECT id, (SELECT channel__r.name,channel__r.account_cohort__c From channel__r) from Marketplace__c

Can anyone help me update this code. Essentially I want the custom object marketplace__c with fields from the account that is a lookup field on the marketplace object. For some reason, the account object is referenced as channel__r on the marketplace.

Answer (score 1):

To query a child, you use:

```
SELECT (SELECT Field1, Field2,... FROM Children) FROM Parent
```

To query a parent, you use:

```
SELECT Parent.Field1, Parent.Field2,... FROM Child
```

Since Marketplace__c has a field named Channel__c that refers to the Account object, you need to use the latter version:

```
SELECT Channel__r.Name, Channel__r.Account_Cohort__c FROM Marketplace__c
```

Comment: I tried that and keep getting the error I was receiving before: Error at row: 1: column: 30. Didnt understand relationship 'marketplace__c" in from part of query call.

Comment: @AndreasPappas What is the exact query?